# Rsync rotating logfiles

Tags: rsync

currently I have an troublesome problem. I needed quite a time for identifying this problem. Anyhow that's what I'm doing:

I collect log files with `rsync` from multiple servers to archive them. Its important to preserve the time attributes so I'm using the archive-mode of `rsync`. But in some cases this leads to some errors.

The problem is that the log files are rotating (changing) on the servers.

So current logs that are in use are named like `test.log` (they are not getting `rsync`ed). After some time and/or a specific file size the log file is rotating. Meaning `test.log` is renamed to `test.log.1`. Now when `test.log` is rotated again, `test.log.1` is renamed to `test.log.2` and `test.log` is renamed to `test.log.1`.

I think when `test.log` would go directly to `test.log.2`, there would be no problem. But that's something I cannot change.

And exactly this rotation happens somehow (sometimes) exactly when I'm `rsync`ing. So `rsync` get all the time-attributes of the files, then the rotation happens and then `rsync` starts to collect the logfiles. But now for example `test.log.1` isn't the same file anymore. But `rsync` gets it anyway. In the end `rsync` can't delete the file on the server because it changed (I see that in the `rsync` debug). I hope that explanation makes sense.

So maybe a small process flow:

1. `rsync` getting a file list with time-attributes (`test.log.1` and `test.log.2`) (that's what I believe is happening, I don't know exactly how 'rsync' works)
2. the logs are rotating (`test.log.1` is now named `test.log.2` and `.2` now `.3`)
3. `rsync` starts collecting (`test.log.1` and `test.log.2`)
4. `rsync` can't delete the specific file

So is there any option that prevents that?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is best solved at the rotation stage, not at the copy-and-archive stage. If you change the log rotation to date the files rather than give them sequential numbers, then the rsync archival doesn't need any logic to do the Right Thing™.

Assuming you are already using logrotate for rotation, then this can be done with the `dateext` option. But if the application is managing its own rotation, it may be harder to configure. I know that log4j can also append dates to the rotated files, but that may not be exposed through configuration and so could require a change to the application. You could also turn off application-level rotation and use logrotate instead.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of a transfer, `rsync` checks that the file it has transferred matches the one is started transferring. If the files mismatch it warns you and moves on to the next one. If you have `--remove-source-files` it will not remove a file that it believes has been incorrectly or incompletely transferred.

Provided that there is a window of opportunity during which `rsync` can successfully transfer the log files, there is no great harm in repeating the `rsync` more frequently - or even repeating it until it succeeds:

```
k=3
while test 0 -lt $k && k=$((k-1))
do
    rsync .... && break
    sleep 10
done
```

If that cannot work for you, you're going to need to think about how you can "snapshot" the log files for long enough to copy:

```
ssh -q remote_host 'mkdir -p rsync.tmp; cp -p *.log rsync.tmp/'
rsync -a --remove-source-files remote_host:/path/to/logs/rsync.tmp/*.log ....
```

Comment: The repeating of rsyinc till it succeed only makes sense if you have an setting for deleting the file on receiver side when deleting on source side fails. I dont think I saw anything familar, or am I wrong? We had the snapshot idea too but it seems a rather "big solution". I think we will work with zfs snapshots.